# Attempting to read open file a second time gets no data

Tags: python

```
fin = open('/abc/xyz/test.txt', 'a+')

def lst():
  return fin.read().splitlines()

print lst()

def foo(in):
  print lst()
  fin.write(str(len(lst()) + in)
  fin.flush()
```

In above code when `print lst()` is called outside function it gives correct result, but when trying to call same function in function `foo()` it produces empty list which makes `len(lst())` value 0. I also tried by commenting last two line but still it gives back empty list. What is wrong in above code?

Comment: Why are you `open`ing `fin` outside `lst()`?

Comment: Do you comment out the first lst() call when you try the one in foo()?

Comment: @olovb No. I put it just to check that lst() is returning expected value.

Comment: Note that you should try using [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for opening files in Python. It's more readable and ensures your file is closed, even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Lattyware Please explain with code eg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File objects are meant to be read once. Once `fin` has been `read()`, you can no longer read anything else from the file since it has already reached `EOF`.

> To read a file’s contents, call f.read(size), which reads some
>   quantity of data and returns it as a string. size is an optional
>   numeric argument. When size is omitted or negative, the entire
>   contents of the file will be read and returned; it’s your problem if
>   the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory. Otherwise, at
>   most size bytes are read and returned. If the end of the file has been
>   reached, f.read() will return an empty string ("").

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

If you really need reentrant access to your file use:

```
def lst():
  fin.seek(0)
  return fin.readlines()
```

Answer (score 5):

Once you read a complete file into memory, reading some more from that file will result in an empty string being returned:

```
>>> example = open('foobar.txt')
>>> example.read()
'Foo Bar\n'
>>> example.read()
''
```

In other words, you have reached the end of the file. You have three alternatives here:

1. Re-open the file for each complete read.
2. Use [`.seek()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to go to the start of the file again:

   ```
   >>> example = open('foobar.txt')
   >>> example.read()
   'Foo Bar\n'
   >>> example.seek(0)
   >>> example.read()
   'Foo Bar\n'
   ```
3. Store the contents of the file in a variable, thus caching it in memory, then use that instead of re-reading the file.

Answer (score 3):

Once you've called [**`read()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) once `fin` has been read.

If you want to `read()` it again (having discarded the contents on the first attempt), you'll need to re-[**`open()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) or [**`seek()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) the start of the file.

I suggest you do this in `lst()`, or, better still, store the contents returned by `lst()`

Aside from that...

```
fin.write(str(len(lst()) + in)
```

It's not clear what you're trying to do here, but you'd be better off using a stored return value from `lst()` and not using `in` as a variable name, since it's a reserved [*keyword*](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).

Something like:

```
lines = lst()
# [...]
number_of_lines = len(lines)
fin.write(str(number_of_lines) + some_other_str)
```

Comment: I think `fin.flush` writes changes stored in I/O buffer into file. I used it because I didn't what to use `file.close()` function.

Comment: What will happen to `bar = fin.read()` if I use `fin.flush()` to update 'fin'? Will it get updated too?

Comment: @Alinwndrld: No, it won't. Try it!

Answer (score 1):

File object can only **read once** which means if you'v called `fin.read()` before the later fin.read() will return nothing.

fix this by call `fin.seek(0)` after call fin.read(), or read file to some buffer.