# Open file and with statement in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, with-statement

Why the second print didn't show ?

**My code:**

```
with open("./learning_python.txt") as file:
    # first print
    print(50*'#')
    content = file.read()
    print(content)
    print(50*'#', end="\n\n")
    # second print
    for line in file:
        print(line.rstrip())
```

**Result:**

```
##################################################
In Python you can Automate the Boring Stuff
In Python you can Stay on Top of Bitcoin Prices
In Python you can Create a Calculator
In Python you can Mine Twitter Data
In Python you can Build a Microblog With Flask
Form https://realpython.com/what-can-i-do-with-python/
##################################################
```

When i make sencod to first:

**Code**

```
with open("./learning_python.txt") as file:
    # second print
    for line in file:
        print(line.rstrip())
    # first print
    print(50*'#')
    content = file.read()
    print(content)
    print(50*'#', end="\n\n")
```

**Result:**

```
In Python you can Automate the Boring Stuff
In Python you can Stay on Top of Bitcoin Prices
In Python you can Create a Calculator
In Python you can Mine Twitter Data
In Python you can Build a Microblog With Flask
Form https://realpython.com/what-can-i-do-with-python/
##################################################

##################################################
```

Why i can't print the file second time ?
How make my code correct ?

Comment: Can you add the contents of learning_python.txt ?

Comment: @Anshuman We can deduce that from the given output already…

Comment: Your cursor or file object position has reached the End Of File (EOF), You need to `seek` it back to start position before re-reading it.

Comment: Thank everyone ! Sloved at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772947/attempting-to-read-open-file-a-second-time-gets-no-data